# Rep changed without telling me why

Tags: support, reputation

I had two tabs open within chrome both of them on SO.  I looked at one and it had this:
[image]

I went back to the other tab on SO and it showed this:
[image]

I thought well where did I lose 15 points and click on my reputation page to see reputation activity (below) and nothing showed up as losing reputation.  Does anyone know why this happened? Was there some global recalc today or something?

[image]

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not know it had to do with accepted answer.  I should of though that since it was 15 points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150651/where-can-i-safe-store-db-password-on-android-application/18150814#18150814) was accepted, then unaccepted because the OP changed his mind.

See the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18150651/timeline):

[image: accept-unaccept-accept]

An accept, unaccept pair on the same day is removed from your reputation graph to reduce clutter, so you won't see that in your graph. I had to go through your recent answers one by one to find this one.

Comment: Awesome, I did not think it that the answer had got accepted let alone be unaccepted or that there was even a timeline feature.  Where on the question screen do you click for that?  I am waiting for the time limit to accept your answer.

Comment: The feature is hidden; I have a [StackApps.com script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) that adds a link.